# Post image to asp.net mvc controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, flash, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to create an asp.net mvc controller method that will return an image generated by a POSTed bytearray. The post is coming from Flash and has the request header: "Content-type", "application/octet-stream" (although this can be changed if needed).

The code I'm trying to implement is from http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/ which gives an example with flash and php as follows:

**AS3**

```
var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/octet-stream");
var jpgURLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("jpg_encoder_download.php?name=sketch.jpg");
jpgURLRequest.requestHeaders.push(header);
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(jpgURLRequest, "_blank");
```

**php**

```
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
    // get bytearray
    $jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

    // add headers for download dialog-box
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['name']);
    echo $jpg;
}
```

Can anyone suggest what an equivilent asp.net MVC controller method might look like?

**ASP.Net MVC**

```
public ActionResult DownloadImage(??? ???)
{
    var myStream:FileStream = ???;
    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(myStream, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may checkout the following [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) which illustrates how file uploads are handled in ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

I have used something similar. Check this out.

```
var image = new Bitmap(Request.InputStream);
string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".jpg";
image.Save(Server.MapPath("somefolder"+fileName));
```

Regards
Parminder